Syncing filters on PowerBI
I have 2 pages that take data from 2 separate tables. Both pages contain a table visualization with the first page having an additional Date dropdown slicer visualization. These tables have a common column "Date" and I have created a relationship for both tables base on that column
For my first page (the main page), I have a slicer filter that selects a single date which then filters the data in table visualization to show me the data base on the selected date.
For my second page, I want the table visualization to show data base on the "Date" filter selected on the first page.
I cannot figure out how to do this.
I have tried: creating relationship between both data tables, applying filter to all pages.

In the end, I fixed by using the same table to build the visualizations on both page, that was the only way it worked for me.

Select your sliicer - Go to view - sycronize slicer - add the flag where you need to sync


Hi! I tried this previously, where I did the synchronization on the first page's slicer.  A second slicer appeared on my second page but I did not make any changes to it. However, changing the date on the first slicer seem to have no effect on my second slicer. Is this the correct approach or am I missing something?

If I understand well, you do it correctly...
If the slicer are the same, copy the first page in the second page and check if everything is synconize

you can try to sync slicers across pages
enter link description here

Link-only answers are not good answers. Please add enough details inside the answer
